# File upload in WordPress

Tags: uploads

I am trying to upload a file through a custom form into WordPress directory but not able to upload it. My code is:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment">


<?php
$uploaddir= '/home/a796f80a/induri.com/attachment/';
$attachment=$uploaddir.basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $attachment);
?>
```

the error I am getting:
 Array ( [attachment] => Array ( [name] => testfile.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpGZYCbR [error] => 0 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: Hello @shashank - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Your question will receive higher quality answers if you elaborate further on the problem you're experiencing - consider adding how you know it doesn't work, any errors you've encountered, and the steps you've tried to troubleshoot it. It also looks like some other necessary information might be missing - how do you submit this custom form? Where is the code you've posted located in your WordPress installation? Take a minute to review the "[ask]" page in our [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious but.. first of all check the permission of the folder you want to upload the file to

Answer (score 0):

May I know what plugin you are using for Uploading the File? If you are using the current version of php & cPanel, And have your WordPress to the latest version, I recommend you using the CALDERA FORMS. Here is the Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/caldera-forms/

So next time you create for example a Job Application form with UPLOAD Button for uploading CV/Resume in .pdf or .docx format, any user can go to your Form Section and Upload the File. And you receive that notification via email that you provide during setting up the Form. ALL FIELDS ARE CUSTOM. You can a Do A Lot :) Thanks & Cheers

Let me know if it worked for you :)
Team FlipSite

Comment: Hi there., I am not using any plugin.

Comment: Try using Caldera

Comment: Thank you. but i don't want to use any plugin